# crontab and ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Tags: python, cron

Im trying to create a cron job that runs every 15 minutes

```
*/15 * * * * cd Desktop && /usr/bin/python myFile.py >> myLog 2>&1
```

When this tries to run, I get this error in `myLog`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

Even though when I run it manually in visual studio code with command `python myFile.py` it runs  with no errors and has no issues with `psycopg2`...any idea whats happening?

Comment: you're probably using a different interpreter in VSCode, check to see what the interpreter path you're using in vsc is and use that for your cronjob

Comment: Im using the VScode terminal, but even when I run the command `python myFile.py` in terminal it still works as expected.

Comment: you're still probably using a different interpreter than `/usr/bin/python`. If that's the case, try using just `python` in your cronjob

Comment: In VSCode, run `which python` to get the path of the executable and use the same path in your cron job

Comment: @CatGirl19 Does it print out when you run it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Your system might be using Python2 by default at `/usr/bin/python`. Check if that is the issue and change it to the path either your Python3 executable path or the path of your virtual environment's executable and run.

Also, a better approach would be to have a shell script be executed via crontab and that script internally either activates your virtual environment or runs the program directly after cd-ing into the directory

Comment: answers shouldn't be based on what "might" be wrong...